# Intersection of any number of compact sets is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

I want to how that in any metric space,

> Intersection of any number of compactsets is compact.

Answer (score 1):

Hint (for metric spaces): a compact set is closed; a closed subset of a compact subset is compact; what about intersections of closed sets?

*Caveat.* “Any number” should be interpreted as “at least one”.

Comment: The intersection of closed set is closed, how can we go further?

Comment: @Saeed It is also contained in at least a compact set, isn't it?

Comment: It is, so it is compact. But this result stems from the fact that we assume the intersection of any number of closed is not empty. To accept this we need that result. Can we proof it using another way?

Comment: @Saeed The empty set is obviously compact.